# When i try to make a textured rectangle my SDL program just goes into black screen

Tags: c++, macos, sdl, sdl-2

I've tried to create a textured rectangle but when i trying to run the program it's just goes into a black screen:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include "dinoHeader.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0){
        return 1;
    }
    
    SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;
    
    
    SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_LoadBMP("./Images/smile.bmp");
    
    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    
    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.w = 100;
    rect.h = 100;
    rect.x = (ScreenWidth / 2) - (rect.w / 2);
    rect.y = (ScreenHeight / 2) - (rect.h / 2);
    
    
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Dino", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    
    game = true;
    
    while (game) {
        SDL_Event event;
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT){
                game = false;
            }
            
        }
        
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &rect);
        
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
    
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using the XCODE.

Comment: You should add error checking to your code. SDL functions generally return `nullptr` on failure, which you can test for and call [`SDL_GetError()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_GetError) to get information about what went wrong.

Comment: Common issues are: your program is running with a different working directory than your source tree, which causes the `SDL_LoadBMP` call to fail. Add error checking and find out.

Answer (score 2):

```
SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;

// ...

SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);

// ...

renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
```

In these lines, you pass `nullptr` to `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`, as renderer isn't created at that point yet. You should use valid working renderer when creating a texture  - so, create renderer first, only then you can use it to create textures.

As said in comments, you should check return values (in that case, your `texture` should be `nullptr`, as texture creation failed), and if they're not as expected - use `SDL_GetError` to inspect error message SDL have set for you.

Comment: @HoloGraphic Good general principle, declare variables and give them their initial value **at the same time**. Lessens the chance of mistakes like this.